# Signal of qubits

Tags: binary, processor

In the basics of digital electronics , I learned that 0 means there is no electronic signal and 1 means the electronic signal is present. All the electronic circuits works on the same mechanism i.e. 1 & 0.

But while surfing on internet, I found DWave Quantom computer, it uses qbit, i.e. it will be 0 and 1.

But how can we represent it in signal scenario? how it will be 0 and 1 both.

Can you please justify.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show enough research effort. Just googling for "quantum computer" brings up lots of resources. Read some of them and then ask about what you don't understand specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing ?

You assume that such a calculation device also works with electronics, voltages, currents etc. Where does it say that it does ? And does it need to ?

It is possible (working devices exist) to build a mechanical computer which uses no voltages at all. Voltage is just a way to store information. Quantum computers use properties of atoms to store information.